# can't call any function inside of onClick function chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular7

I cannot call any function inside of the onClick function of chart.js. cannot even change public variable values.

```
initializeGraph() {
 this.graph = new Chart('graph', {
  type: 'pie',
   data: {
    datasets: [{
     data: [1,2],
      backgroundColor: ['#RRGGBB', '#FF0000'],
     }],
      labels: ['blue','red']
    },
   options: {
    onClick : function(event,elements) {
     this.hello();
    }
   }
  });
 }

 hello() {
  console.log("i am here");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try

```
initializeGraph() {
    const that = this;
    this.graph = new Chart('graph', {
        type: 'pie',
          data: {
            datasets: [{
              data: [1,2],
              backgroundColor: ['#RRGGBB', '#FF0000'],
            }],
            labels: ['blue','red']
          },
          options: {
           onClick : function(event,elements) {
              that.hello();
            }
          }
     });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using arrow function? `(e) => {}`
The `this` variable’s scope is different when using arrow function.
The arrow function inherit the ‘this’ from the parent scope, which in your case might refers to global scope.

Comment: You mean like this :        onClick : function((elements) => {
          hello();
        })

Comment: No, arrow function is another way to write function in ES6, e is the event handler in your case. Check the link below.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions